# Django HTTP GET Security

Tags: django

On my homepage, I have a random poll for each visitor. Upon loading the homepage, an automatic HTTP GET triggers my view to generate a unique session ID for that poll. This is to ensure that the user is indeed voting on the poll that I randomly generated for them in my view instead of just manually constructing their own HTTP POST to vote on the polls they want.

However, with that initial HTTP GET, I also save the unique id to my database so I can validate their future POST. Does this produce a security issue if the user was to spam my homepage with HTTP GETs to trigger multiple database writes?

I understand that HTTP GET should not change the state of my application, but is this a time when it is appropriate for an HTTP GET to do so? If not, how would I fix this dilemma?

When I span my server with HTTP GETs, I get the following error. Is this error coming from excess writes to my database or something else?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 86, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 127, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 210, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 268, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 195, in send_preamble
    self._write('Server: %s\r\n' % self.server_software)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 324, in write
    self.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 58092)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 582, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 139, in __init__
    super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 640, in __init__
    self.finish()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 693, in finish
    self.wfile.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
    self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: The errors probably are coming from an overloaded server, not from your app. I didn't really understand what you were trying to achieve though, care to re-word?

Comment: Yes definitely, I reworded it the best I could :) Thanks for your insight about the overloaded server, is this something that could be fixed upon deploying this on a production server as opposed to a development server?

Comment: Using a production server will let you serve a lot more users, yes. Regarding your use case, I don't really understand what it is with displaying a poll for a single user.

Comment: The issue is that every time I display the poll (HTTP GET), an entry with a unique session ID gets written to my database. Could someone possibly exploit this by trying to flood my database with entries by continuously refreshing the page with multiple users in order to spam HTTP GET requests?

Comment: Well, anytime an user accesses your site without an session cookie, Django generates a session ID for them too, so I'd suggest you don't overthink it. You can / should monitor the activity to detect flooding attempts though.

Comment: +1 for planning for the worst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a concern for you, then you could [configure the sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) to not use the database. You have other options: cookie-based, file-based (maybe not much better than using the database) and cache (memory, which is not a good alternative in this case). Cookie-based sessions will have the data stored on the user's machines, which is good if you're worried about a spam attacks filling up your server with session data, but bad if you're worried about cookie manipulation attacks. However, django cookies are signed and use a secret key. Hope this helps!